# Cannot compare java.util.ArrayList and java.lang.Integer

Tags: grails, collections, groovy

I'm trying to filter a list of location objects to get back filtered list of objects.

```
   def result= ports?.locations?.findAll { 

        it.numberOfParkingSlots > 0
}
```

But I got the following exception:

```
Cannot compare java.util.ArrayList with value '[0, 3]' and java.lang.Integer with value '0'. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot compare java.util.ArrayList with value '[0, 3]' and java.lang.Integer with value '0'
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `numberOfParkingSlots.size() > 0`?

Comment: Looks like variable numberOfParkingSlots is ArrayList. How do you want to compare it with single integer ?

Comment: No. It is an integer int numberOfParkingSlots;

Comment: as per your snippet it is NOT an integer

Comment: Which snippet? How is that?

Comment: `Cannot compare java.util.ArrayList with value '[0, 3]' and java.lang.Integer with value '0'.`. It states clearly `it.numberOfParkingSlots` is an ArrayList and not an integer. Unless this exception is not related to that line

Comment: Actually this is what makes me crazy. It is a property of class Location of type int and the exception is saying it is an arraylist

Comment: Try inserting some output. Add `println it.numberOfParkingSlots.getClass()` right before `it.numberOfParkingSlots > 0`

Comment: java.util.ArrayList. Does findAll method converts ints into array list?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55091/discussion-between-will-p-and-feras-odeh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ports` variable sounds like a list, and so does `locations`. When a getter is called on a list, Groovy does a list unpack and the result looks like a collect: the property from all the objects is put inside a list, thus, your error. I managed to reproduce your error with the following:

```
class Port { 
    List<Location> locations = [] 
}

class Location { 
    int numberOfParkingSlots 
}

ports = [
    new Port(locations: [ 
        new Location(numberOfParkingSlots: 0), 
        new Location(numberOfParkingSlots: 3) ]),
    new Port(locations: [ new Location(numberOfParkingSlots: 1) ]),
]

ports?.locations?.findAll { 
  it.numberOfParkingSlots > 0 
}
```

Which fails with:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: 
    Cannot compare java.util.ArrayList with value '[0, 3]' and 
    java.lang.Integer with value '0'
```

I'm assuming this is the case here.

The problem is that `ports.location` is getting a list of lists, and inside `findAll`, `it` is a list of locations. A solution is to `flatten()` the lists befores invoking `findAll`:

```
def locations = ports?.locations.flatten().findAll {
  it.numberOfParkingSlots > 0
}

assert locations[0].numberOfParkingSlots == 3
assert locations[1].numberOfParkingSlots == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use isEmpty()?

```
     def result= ports?.locations?.findAll { !it.numberOfParkingSlots.empty }
```

Comment: numberOfParkingSlots is an integer not an arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Or just using groovy truth

```
def result= ports?.locations?.findAll { it.numberOfParkingSlots }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the code you share, you could try adding toInteger() method to numberOfParkingSlots **property**

something like this

```
def result= ports?.locations?.findAll { 
    it.numberOfParkingSlots.toInteger() > 0
}
```

I have not tried this, some proposed options are plausibles, i hope it help you